# Caja only shows images and icons preview when root

Tags: mate, thumbnails, caja

I'm looking for the solution to this error for some time . I did not find anywhere.

Caja could only see the icons of the images and videos when at root. How can I enable this functionality in normal mode, without superuser on caja ?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Please open the file manager or Caja then show the hidden files by pressing Ctrl+H and check this directory /home/YOUR_USER/.cache .. you will find that the folder "thumbnails" is owned by root not by YOUR_USER!

you can fix that with terminal :

```
sudo chown -R YOUR_USER '/home/YOUR_USER/.cache/thumbnails'
```

that would fix the permission issue and the thumbnails will be shown up normally :)

Answer (score 0):

Open Caja the go to: *Edit→Preferences→Preview→Other previewable file→Show thumbnails→Always*.

I use Mate in Spanish, here put the sections/menu names as I believe that be.